# Swagger in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, serverless-framework

I have documented my Dotnet Core API with Swagger (Swashbuckle) on my local machine. 
Now I am have deployed my API through the Serverless framework to AWS but Swagger is not working!!
I tried to add Open API to AWS API GateWay but it didn't work also!
Any ideas on how to do it??
I expect to get the Swagger UI when I navigate to [https:/MyAmazonApi/Development/swagger](https://https:/MyAmazonApi/Development/swagger) 
but instead of that, I get 
**{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}**
Which is some generic error from Amazon web services.
Please note: I don't have any authentication implemented.

This is my current code:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
services.AddMvc();
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Hi Api", Description = "This is a serverless Swagger" });
        });
```

}

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        RegisterServicesToContainer(app);


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }


       app.UseMvc();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(
            c =>
           c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Hello Swagger"));


    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what "is not working" means. What result do you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: I expect to get the Swagger UI when I navigate to https:/MyAmazonApi/Development/swagger

but instead of that I get
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} Which is some generic error from Amazon web services. Please note: I don't have any authentication implemented.